# How to get a list of site/subsite users with permissions?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, permissions

I have a company SharePoint Online portal (https://company.sharepoint.com) containing a number of sub-sites - some of them with sub-sub-sites. How can I get a list that shows all users on the portal with (sub-)sub-sites each user has access to (plus, the type of access rights, preferably)? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way: use SharePoint Online PnP Module via PowerShell.

Reference: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Get-SharePoint-Online-and-7e6afce2

Answer (score 0):

Using powershell, try this script:

```
Import-Module 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll'
Import-Module 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll'
Import-Module 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Publishing.dll'

$url ="<your site URL>"
$context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($url)

$userCollection = $context.Web.SiteUsers
        $context.Load($userCollection)
        $context.ExecuteQuery()

        foreach ($user in $userCollection)
        {
            $userName = $user.LoginName
            Add-Content -Path C:\logs.log -Value $userName
            Add-Content -Path C:\logs.log -Value "-----------------------------------"
            $permissions = $context.Web.GetUserEffectivePermissions($user.LoginName)
            $context.ExecuteQuery()
            $PermissionKindObj=New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.PermissionKind
            $PermissionKindType=$PermissionKindObj.getType()

            foreach ($permissionKind in [System.Enum]::GetValues($PermissionKindType))
            {
                $type=$permissionKind.getType()
                $permisson = [System.Enum]::GetName($type, $permissionKind)
                $hasPermisssion = $permissions.Value.Has($permissionKind);
                if ($hasPermisssion)
                {
                    Add-Content -Path C:\logs.log -Value $permissionKind.ToString()                    
                }
            }
        }
```

[Source](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/232314/sharepoint-online-all-user-access-permissions-report)

Answer (score 0):

If you already have ShareGate inhouse then it is one of the default reports available. Otherwise get the free 14 days trial if you just need a snapshot right now

Answer (score 0):

This writes to a .csv

```
foreach ($site in  ($sites = Get-SPOSite -limit All)) {
$users = Get-SPOUser -Site $site
foreach ($user in $users){
    $data = [PSCustomObject]@{
        "Site Url" = $site.url
        "User Login" = $user.loginname
        "Groups" = $user.Groups
        "User Type" = $user.usertype
    }
$data | Export-Csv -Append -NoTypeInformation c:\temp\spo-output.csv 
}
}
```